# Options for handling a frequently changing data form

Tags: forms, crud

What are some possible designs to deal with frequently changing data forms?

I have a basic CRUD web application where the main data entry form changes yearly. So each record should be tied to a specific version of the form. This requirement is kind of new, so the existing application was not built with this in mind.

I'm looking for different ways of handling this, hoping to avoid future technical debt. Here are some options I've come up with:

- Create a new object, UI and set of tables for each version. This is obviously the most naive approach.
- Keep adding all the fields to the same object and DB tables, but show/hide them based on the form version. This will become a mess after a few changes.
- Build form definitions, then dynamically build the UI and store the data as some dictionary like format (e.g. JSON/XML or maybe an document oriented database) I think this is going to be too complex for the scope of this app, especially for the UI.

What other possibilities are there? Does anyone have experience doing this? I'm looking for some design patterns to help deal with the complexity.

Comment: Really a good question. Its an area one need to look at. Definitely a +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular app, we decided to deal with the problem as if there was one form that continuously grows. Due to the nature of the form this seemed more natural than more explicit separation. We will have a mapping of year->field for parts of the application that do need to know which data is for which year.

For the UI, we will be creating a new page for each year's form. Dynamic form creation is far too complex in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

First, I will speak to your solutions above and then I will give my answer.

- Creating a new table for each
  version is going to require new
  programming every year since you will
  not be able to dynamically join to
  the new table and include the new
  columns easily.  That seems pretty obvious and really makes this a bad choice.
- The issues you mentioned with adding 
  the columns to the same form are
  correct.  Also, whatever database you
  are using has a max on how many
  columns it can handle and how many
  bytes it can have in a row.  That could become another concern.
- The third option I think is the
  closest to what you want.  I would
  not store the new column data in a
  JSON/XML unless it is for duplication
  to increase speed.  I think this is
  your best option
- The only option you didn't mention
  was storing all of the data in 1
  database field and using XML to
  parse.  This option would make it
  tough to query and write reports
  against.

If I had to do this:

1. The first table would have the
   columns ID (seeded), Name,
   InputType, CreateDate,
   ExpirationDate, and CssClass. I
   would call it tbInputs.
2. The second table would have the have
   5 columns, ID, Input_ID (with FK to
   tbInputs.ID), Entry_ID (with FK to
   the main/original table) value, and
   CreateDate.  The FK to the
   main/original table would allow you
   to find what items were attached to
   what form entry. I would call this
   table tbInputValues.
3. If you don't
      plan on having that base table then
      I would use a simply table that tracks the creation date, creator ID,
   and the form_id.
4. Once you have those you will just need to create a dynamic form that pulls back all of the inputs that are currently active and display them.  I would put all of the dynamic controls inside of some kind of container like a `<div>` since it will allow you to loop through them without knowing the name of every element.  Then insert into tbInputValues the ID of the input and its value.
5. Create a form to add or remove an
   input.  This would mean you would
   not have much if any maintenance
   work to do each year.

I think this solution may not seem like the most eloquent but if executed correctly I do think it is your most flexible solution that requires the least amount of technical debt.

Comment: In a general sense, this is what I meant by my third point. Another downside to this is more complex forms require more complex code to generate the form. e.g. fields dependent on each other, complex validation

Comment: I think you are getting into a pretty complicated area in general.  I don't know if there will be any easy answers.  Have you looked to see if there are any controls that exist to download that will solve your problem?

Comment: I wouldn't expect an easy solution. And every app with this requirement would be different too. That's why I started this discussion. 

I have spent a small amount of time looking for solutions, but I think it would be hard to retrofit something like that onto the existing code. Maybe for someone just starting this would be the way to go. I also have a hard time imagining a generic solution giving as good a user experience as hand coded forms.

Answer (score 2):

I think the third approach (XML) is the most flexible. A simple XML structure is generated very fast and can be easily versioned and validated against an XSD.

You'd have a table holding the XML in one column and the year/version this xml applies to.

Generating UI code based on the schema is basically a bad idea. If you do not require extensive validation, you can opt for a simple editable table.

If you need a custom form every year, I'd look at it as kind of a job guarantee :-) It's important to make the versioning mechanism and extension transparent and explicit though.